# PHP remove equals sometimes quoted_printable_decode

Tags: php

I have an HTML email string that is created using quoted_printable_decode but it is adding an equals randomly for some reason.  How can I either stop the random "=" from getting inserted into the string or search and replace the string to remove the "=" but not if it should be there.

example:
$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2));

will output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><pros=pect status="new">...etc
```

I want to keep the = where it says status="new"  but not have the = in the middle of the word prospect

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suspect you just `echo $message` and it loses all the newlines they were there originally?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly but the output I posted is the echo $message

Comment: If you check it in browser - try to see the page source, not the rendered result: there you will see that the message is formatted **correctly** with new lines.

Comment: This is all at the code level, I am not viewing this in a browser window at all.

Comment: Then you need a better explanation of a problem: `quoted_printable_decode` generates a correct output (unless it's a bug in which case you should report it).